# How can I get the shortest path with the BFS algorithm using a map in Java?

Tags: java, breadth-first-search

I have been playing around with BFS as described here:

https://tutorialedge.net/artificial-intelligence/breadth-first-search-java/

However, the algorithm proposed in the tutorial is only able to tell if the goalNode has been found. 
Also, it allows to have just 2 adjacent nodes.

Therefore, I made some modifications to the original algorithm, however I am not able to make it work as supposed.

I have tried to integrate the suggestion from @sandeepraj-tandon without success.

[Counting levels in Breadth First Search (Distance between start node and goal node)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22580149/counting-levels-in-breadth-first-search-distance-between-start-node-and-goal-no)

EDIT: as per your request I will write here a complete minimal example

```
package davide.pugliese.v2;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

@SuppressWarnings("Duplicates")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DirectorV2 {

  public static void build() {
    Node station1 = new Node("1", new ArrayList<>());
    Node station2 = new Node("2", new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton(station1)));
    Node station3 = new Node("3", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(station1, station2)));
    Node station4 = new Node("4", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(station2, station3)));
    Node station5 = new Node("5", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(station4, station3)));
    Node station6 = new Node("6", new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(station5, station4)));
    new Bfs(station5 , station1).getShortestDistancePath();

  }
}
```

```
package davide.pugliese.v2;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.*;

@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Bfs {

  private Node startNode;
  private Node endNode;

  public void getShortestDistancePath() {

    List<Path> pathLists = new LinkedList<>();
    Queue<Node> sameLevelNodes = new LinkedList<>();

    if (startNode.equals(endNode)) {

      var path = Path.builder().startNode(startNode).endNode(endNode).distance(0).build();
      System.out.println(path);

    } else {

      sameLevelNodes.offer(startNode);

      var distance = 0;

      while (!sameLevelNodes.isEmpty()) {

        var current = sameLevelNodes.poll();
        if (current.equals(endNode)) {

          var newPath = new Path(startNode, current, distance);
          Set<Path> tempSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(pathLists);
          tempSet.add(newPath);
          pathLists = new LinkedList<>(tempSet);
          distance = 0;
        }

        if (!current.getNeighborList().isEmpty()) {
          sameLevelNodes.addAll(current.getNeighborList());
        }

        distance++;
      }
    }
    System.out.println(keepPathWithShortestDistance(pathLists));
  }

  private List<Path> keepPathWithShortestDistance(List<Path> paths) {

    List<Path> pathsCopy = new LinkedList<>(paths);

    for (Path path : paths) {
      for (Path path2 : paths) {
        if (path.getDistance() < path2.getDistance()) {
          pathsCopy.remove(path2);
        }
      }
    }
    return pathsCopy;
  }
}
```

```
package davide.pugliese.v2;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * The Node class represents a station in this tutorial and will as such have a string representing
 * the station's name. As well as an ArrayList of nodes that will store any instantiated nodes
 * children.
 */
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Node {

  public String name;
  private List<Node> neighborList;
}
```

```
package davide.pugliese.v2;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Path {

    private Node startNode;
    private Node endNode;
    private Integer distance;

}
```

The algorithm at the moment returns:

```
[Path(startNode=Node(name=5, neighborList=[Node(name=4, neighborList=[Node(name=2, neighborList=[Node(name=1, neighborList=[])]), Node(name=3, neighborList=[Node(name=1, neighborList=[]), Node(name=2, neighborList=[Node(name=1, neighborList=[])])])]), Node(name=3, neighborList=[Node(name=1, neighborList=[]), Node(name=2, neighborList=[Node(name=1, neighborList=[])])])]), endNode=Node(name=1, neighborList=[]), distance=1)]
```

The computed distance is 1, whereas it should be 2 for the chosen couple of nodes "5" and "1".

Which obviously is not correct.

[image: Graph illustration]

What is wrong in my code?

The graph shows the stations orientated in an arbitrary order that reflects the one chosen when creating each node with its neighbour.

My goal is to calculate the distance for each path and choose the one with the shortest distance.

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT: I realize now that Path is not actually the best name for that class, but I don't have a better name ad the moment... Maybe NodeCouple...

Comment: SO is not meant to be a coding service. General advice is: understand what you are trying to do and then step through your program to compare if it's doing the right thing. Do you have some question about the algorithm? Are you unclear about how to implement it? Have you implemented everything but the behavior is not correct?

Comment: Please update your question to better reflect what your question is.

Comment: It seems to go bad immediately at the neighbors of the first node. What you're supposed to do at each step is cycle through the neigbors of the current node and give them a distance "current+1" unless they already have a lower distance.

Comment: Well, what I am trying to do is to save all the paths found, having as a start point startNode and destination goalNode into a Map data structure and then, based on the size of the lists containing the data, determine which is the shortest path (as it contains less nodes). It starts to go bad from Start node 2, Destination node 1

Comment: ok, then at each node you are supposed to do (pseudocode): for each neighbor of current: does it have a path from root? (then) do nothing  (else) its path = my path + neighbor; add neighbor to BFS queue for processing later

Comment: and first step is root path = (root); add root to queue; start main loop...

Comment: Add a visual of the graph please, and make your code Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: add `Node` and `Intermediate` classes and test data

Comment: @c0der, I applied the required changes.

Comment: Some comments:  A. to make the code [mcve] you need to remove dependency on unavailable resources including `lombok`.   B. The graph and and the definition of neighbors do not match. For example "station 1" should have 2 neighbors, and "station 4" should have 4.

Comment: Your while loop will traverse the graph from start to end (unless the graph has a cycle, then the loop will never end). Once it has reached the end, it will start faffing about with some paths.

Comment: I think you should move some of that logic into an else (current is not end node) inside the loop. Mark where you've been (see the inifinite loop thing). And also build some partial paths while you are underway. When you have reached the end, it's too late to build anything...